# How to use dataType setting in jquery.ajax() method to receive a fetched object of mysql database?

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, json, ajax

Sorry, I'm latin so my english is not good, I'm trying to get a fetched object of mysql database but I never before has used `$.ajax()` method and the result of `alert(response.word)` is `undefined`, someone could help me with this trouble and show me a bit how `dataType: "json"` setting works? as the information in the JQuery Documentation API is not very illustrative for me. Thanks in advance...!

**indexScript.js**

```
dictionarySearchForm.on("submit", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
      url: "dictionary/search.php",
      type: "get",
      dataType: "json",
      data: { wordToSearch: wordToSearch.val() },
      success: function(response){
         alert(response.word);
      },
      error: function(){
         alert("Fail...!");
      }
   });
});
```

**search.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET["wordToSearch"])){

    include_once("../connection/connection.php");

    $word = $_GET["wordToSearch"];

    $connection = Connection::getConnection();
    $query = "select * from english_dictionary_table where word like ':wordMarker%'";
    $result = $connection->prepare($query);
    $result->execute(array(":wordMarker" => $word));
    $arrayRegisters = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    echo(json_encode($arrayRegisters));

}

?>
```

**connection.php**

```
<?php
class Connection{
    public static function getConnection(){
        $dbHost = "localhost";
        $dbName = "test_database";
        $dbUser = "root";
        $dbPassword = "";
        $connection = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbName; host=$dbHost", $dbUser, $dbPassword);
        $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return($connection);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Try to `console.log(response);` inside your success function to check the value of `response`

Comment: Maybe you need to `console.log(response[0].word);` | Maybe you are receiving an array, so you need to access the first element of the array.